# Kubernetes delete deployment signal

Tags: python, kubernetes, sigterm

I have the following `python` code:

```
import time
import os
import signal
from abc import abstractmethod

class Stopper:
    stop = False
    
    @staticmethod
    def safe_stop(*args):
        Stopper.stop = true


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, Stopper.safe_stop)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, Stopper.safe_stop)

while not Stopper.stop:
    print("Running...")
    time.sleep(1)

os.system("touch /mnt/pod/sig")
print("Done")
```

And I create a deployment that contains an image with the above Python code.

When I delete the deployment using `kubectl delete -f sig.yaml` my Python code does not create the sig file indication and it's not printing the "Done" message.

At this link: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace I see that k8s send *SIGINT*, *SIGTERM* signals but nothing happens in my application.

How can I make k8s send the signal to my application? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could it be because of typo in `signal.singal`?

Comment: oh,sorry, typo - I fixed it

Comment: If you run this outside Kubernetes (either stopping the program with `^C` or kill(1)) does it work?  The `@abstractmethod` doesn't seem right, and I suspect you're correctly receiving the signal but the function call is failing.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, If I run it and stop the progam ^C it's wokring for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Python code. You need to adjust the class arguments and use `Stopper.stop = True` (with capitalized `T`).

The following code worked with Python 3:

```
import time
import os
import signal
from abc import abstractmethod

class Stopper:
    stop = False
    
    @abstractmethod
    def safe_stop(self, args):
        Stopper.stop = True


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, Stopper.safe_stop)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, Stopper.safe_stop)

while not Stopper.stop:
    print("Running...")
    time.sleep(1)

os.system("touch /mnt/pod/sig")
print("Done")
```

Comment: Hi, I fix the typo but it still not working